What is the average value of a function in polar coordinates?
The answer at https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/average-value-and-area-in-polar.555899/ is the following, saying to divide by apparently the arc length:
"The average value of a function in polar coordinates can be calculated by finding the average of the function’s values at different points on the polar curve. This can be done by dividing the integral of the function over the entire curve by the length of the curve."
On the other hand, the implication at Mean value of $r$ with respect to $\theta$ between two limits of a polar curve is to divide by the interval length.
Should the area be divided by the arc length or else the interval length?

Studying the document at https://www.mit.edu/~hlb/StantonGrant/Lecture23/example23.1.pdf, I believe that either can be the divisor, depending on the interpretation.
